# variables not translating after = sign

Tags: powershell

losing my mind here lol. I am trying to use PowerShell to automate driver extraction. I do a lot of this for building driver packages for MECM so figured I would try some automation. My issue is getting the script to translate the variables after Dir=. I tried with single and double quotes, I tried escaping the quotes, but I still end up with the variable rather than the translated string.

```
$Extracted = "C:\Temp2\Extracted" 
$DriverPKGFolder = Read-Host -Prompt "enter the name of the folder the extraction will create"
Get-ChildItem -Path c:\temp2\driverdownloads -Filter *.exe -Depth 1 | ForEach {
write-host $_.Fullname
Start-Process $_.Fullname -ArgumentList '/Extract="YES" /DIR=$Extracted\$DriverPKGFolder' -Wait
}
```

I tried it this way:

```
$Extracted = "C:\Temp2\Extracted" 
$DriverPKGFolder = Read-Host -Prompt "enter the name of the folder the extraction will create"
Get-ChildItem -Path c:\temp2\driverdownloads -Filter *.exe -Depth 1 | ForEach {
write-host $_.Fullname
Start-Process $_.Fullname -ArgumentList '/Extract="YES" /DIR=$("$Extracted\$DriverPKGFolder")' -Wait
```

And got this:

[image]

And this way:

```
$Extracted = "C:\Temp2\Extracted" 
$DriverPKGFolder = Read-Host -Prompt "enter the name of the folder the extraction will create"
Get-ChildItem -Path c:\temp2\driverdownloads -Filter *.exe -Depth 1 | ForEach {
write-host $_.Fullname
Start-Process $_.Fullname -ArgumentList '/Extract="YES" /DIR="$Extracted\$DriverPKGFolder"' -Wait
}
```

And got this:

[image]

Comment: many ways to do it, `-ArgumentList ('/Extract="YES" /DIR="{0}\{1}"' -f $Extracted, $DriverPKGFolder)` might be an option

Comment: In short: In PowerShell, only `"..."` strings (double-quoted aka _expandable strings_) perform string interpolation (expansion of variable values and expressions), not `'...'` strings (single-quoted aka _verbatim strings_). With `"..."` quoting, if the string value itself contains `"` chars., escape them as `\`"` or `""`, or use a double-quoted _here-string_.  See the linked duplicate and the conceptual [about_Quoting_Rules](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules) help topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, here's a few tips:

If you're inside double quoted strings you can ...

wrap your variable names with `{}` eg:

```
PS C:\Users\MyUsername> Write-Host "${Extracted}\${DriverPKGFolder}"
C:\Temp\Extracted\dsadasd
```

you can wrap your variables in `$()` to execute expressions like upper or lower casing filenames eg:

```
PS C:\Users\MyUsername> Write-Host "$($Extracted.ToLower())\$($DriverPKGFolder.ToUpper())"
c:\temp\extracted\DSADSA
```

you can embed double quotes into a double quoted string by escaping them like:

```
PS C:\Users\MyUsername> Write-Host "my `"quoted`" string"
my "quoted" string
```

you can use the "heredoc" syntax which looks like this:

```
PS C:\Users\MyUsername> $ImAHeredocString=@"
combination of "quotes" and 'Single' quotes & $($Extracted) variables 
"@
Write-Host $ImAHeredocString
Example of "quotes" and 'Single' quotes & C:\Temp\Extracted variables
```

(The important point is `"@` cant have any whitespace before it)

As @Santiago points out, you can often pass arguments as arrays; I like to explicitly define an array so that PowerShell doesn't get confused:

```
-ArgumentList @('/Extract="YES"', "/DIR=`"$($Extracted)\$($DriverPKGFolder)`"" )
```

Comment: Wow, definitely appreciate the suggestions, I went with your post:-ArgumentList @('/Extract="YES"', "/DIR=`"$($Extracted)\$($DriverPKGFolder)`"" )

Comment: That should work fine, but remember you should really use the simpler `${}` whenever you can if you dont plan to do anything with the variable(other then output it). So `$($Extracted)\$($DriverPKGFolder)` would become: `${Extracted}\${DriverPKGFolder}` if you wanted to follow best practice. (but its totally optional - but it is a good idea)